# Swift Coordinate System View

Tags: swift, coordinate-systems

I recently checked out the Swift Playgrounds App available inside the App Store where I stumbled across this interactive coordinate system view similar to the one that can be found inside of Xcode playgrounds on the Mac.

[image: Swift Playgrounds]

My question is if this framework is accessible for developers or if it's something Apple developed internally for the playground?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like apple is using it internally. But you can build it yourself see this [blogpost](https://medium.com/@tstenerson/lets-make-a-line-chart-in-swift-3-5e819e6c1a00) for inspiration. However it's written in Swift 3 but it should be easily transferable to Swift 4.